# Office 2007 network share access denied

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, microsoft-office-2007

Hope I have not duplicated an issue already posted but I could not find anything from the search...

Right here is the problem, we have recently updated all our desktops to the MS Office 2007 suite and people have issues trying to open simple files like word documents...

the systems are

Windows XP (SP3)

Novell Network with novell client

Office 2007

when they try to open a word document from a usual network share word presents a message reporting

Access Denied Contact Administrator

So we assumed network permissions, none of which have changed...so try the same file with Wordpad and it opens fine, be it with formating issues of course...

Now copy the file to your desktop, which is not redirected, and you can open the file in word as normal...

so does anyone know if office 2007 uses some new permission when opening files? does it create temps or something...

any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Well after every windows update known to mankind and .net framework...got me nowhere..

But a fresh install of Windows XP, service packs and updates...then install Office 2007 all is good...

So the only solution I have so far is a fresh install :(

Hope someone knows a better one or no one has the same problem

*UPDATE*

It now seems that users that log off and then log back in receive the access denied message, it all works if the machine is rebooted...

Comment: That ain't nice. It might be an Office 2007 bug, or a Microsoft stab-old-OS-in-the-back type thing, but I would look into GPO trouble. Try to find out from Microsoft what Office 2007 is doing differently to Office 2003. If you are sharing files from 2008 server, have you tried toggling SMB2 features?

Answer (score 0):

What anti-virus/protection apps do you have running on those machines? We're using CA eTrust ITM and occasionally have this issue. I've searched for the problem online and have found reports of the same thing happening, but I haven't found any good solution -- fortunately for us, it happens infrequently (enough that I've been able to get by so far without finding a solution).

Answer (score 0):

If your using CA ITM make sure you are not scanning network drives on the server or the computers that contain you Microsoft Office saved files. Just scan the local drives on the server and computers and leave network drives unchecked. All will return to normal. Good Luck -- Yiper72